# Append the previous value of a column in most optimized way without using case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Below is my T-SQL

```
Update Table1
Set Note = CONCAT(Note, ', ', @Note)
```

If in the above query Note is null or empty I want to avoid appending in that case
my query should behave like

```
Update Table1
Set Note=@Note
```

I think there are better and optimized way to do this so just searching for that option. I can write the query using case.

Comment: Hi Dale. I think there are better and optimized way to do this so just searching for that option. I can write the query using case.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks Dale. I will use case once I don't find any other better way

Comment: @Dale Actually I was thinking of using some TSQL function which might be available for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `coalesce` because when using the `+` operator any `null` results in `null` as opposed to `concat` which handles null values as an empty string.

```
update Table1 set Note = coalesce(Note + ', ' + @Note, @Note)
```

But this doesn't handle the case when Note is an empty string. You need a `case` expression for that.

Actually you can handle the empty string case as follows:

```
update Table1 set Note = coalesce(nullif(Note,'') + ', ' + @Note, @Note)
```

But in my opinion that is more complex than using a simple `case` expression:

```
update Table1 set
  Note = case when coalesce(Note,'') <> '' then concat(Note, ', ', @Note) else @Note end
```

The `case` expression is an integral part of T-SQL so I wouldn't be concerned about using it.

Further: [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is actually a `case` under the hood anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Dale K's 1st answer:

```
Update Table1 Set Note = CONCAT(NULLIF(Note, '') + ', ', @Note)
```

Parts explained:

`NULLIF(Note, '')` is used to turn an empty Note into `NULL`.

`NULL + 'something'` evaluates to: `NULL`.

`CONCAT(NULL, 'something')` evaluates to :  `'something'`.